# WxWidgets File Dialog problems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm having a bit of trouble in my attempts to learn WXWidgets. I'm currently trying to work with file Dialogs, and I've got one opening just fine. But I run into trouble whenever I try to apply styles to the window. I get an undeclared identifier for whatever style I use.

My code is as follows (yes, I know, hello world app. I'm experimenting with all the things I need to learn to do before actually making a fully fledged app)

```
    #include "wx/wx.h"
    #include "wx/filedlg.h"

    #include "HelloWorldApp.h"

    IMPLEMENT_APP(HelloWorldApp)

    bool HelloWorldApp::OnInit()
    {
        wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame((wxFrame*) NULL, -1, _T("Hello wxWidgets World"));


        wxFileDialog* OpenDialog = new wxFileDialog(frame, _("Choose a file to open"), wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, 
            _("Image Files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp|Sound Files (*.wav, *.mp3)|*.wav;*.mp3"),
wxFD_MULTIPLE);

        frame->CenterOnScreen();
        frame->Show(true);

        OpenDialog->ShowModal();

        SetTopWindow(frame);
        return true;
    }
```

It runs just fine without the "wxFD_MULTIPLE" argument. I'm using version 2.8.12 of wxWidgets.

Thanks for reading. I really appreciate any help or guidance anyone can give. Sorry if it's something really obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Could you paste the build log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very old wxWidgets versions (2.6), this style was known as `wxMULTIPLE` but `wxFD_MULTIPLE` is definitely available in any 2.8.x version. You should give the (beginning of) the errors you get to allow us to understand what is really going on.

Completely independently, your code is wrong because it contains a memory leak: the dialog must be destroyed as modal dialogs are exceptions to the usual rule that all windows should be allocated on the heap and can be allocated on the stack, i.e. used as simple local variables, see [the example in the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_dialog.html#details). Looking at the "dialogs" sample code is also strongly recommended.

Comment: Alright. The error in question was

error C2065: 'wxFD_MULTIPLE' : undeclared identifier

However, I tried your 2.6 version. And oddly enough, it works. O.o I don't know why it's working with old code (I downloaded the 2.8.12 version, and the folder says it is). So I'll have to work to try and get it to compile the proper code. Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have figured out I was somehow using an older version without your help.

Comment: I think you must have a problem with your include paths and are using 2.6 headers when you think you're using 2.8 ones and/or vice versa.